# Need to select Excel range of cells from A1 to found text from imported text file

Tags: excel

I have just imported a un-formatted text file into a worksheet. I need to select and delete the rows of data from Cell A1 to the words "NoRx Report"

What would be the code to do that?

Comment: You'll need to make an effort to do this on your own.  We generally don't write code for you, but rather help you address specific problems you're running into.  To get started, you'll want to take a look at the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method.  If you get stuck, edit your question to include what code you've tried.

Comment: For more info on what @tigeravatar wrote, see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show what have you done so far. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, but people will be glad to help if you provide more details and have a specific question about your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete the rows up to and including the row with the text:

```
Sub dural()
   Range(Range("A1"), Range("A:A").Find(what:="NoRx Report", after:=Range("A1"))).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```